# Integral calculus use of Newton-Leibnitz rule

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, definite-integrals

My friend asked me this question:

If $y(x)= \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin{(px-pt)}dt$ then what is the value of $y''(x)-((p^2)*y(x))$ ?

He gave me the hint to consider $\sin(px-pt)$ as the imaginary part of the complex number $e^{i(px-pt)}$ but this just confused me only more. Please help.

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler's formula? It says $$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x).$$ Using that, you can write $$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}.$$ Because the variable $x$ also appears in the integral, this is not a straight-forward application of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. The idea is to somehow remove this x from the integral, so then you can apply the product rule. If the complex stuff bothers you, the same can be accomplished using the difference formula for the sine function.

Answer (score 1):

Write $$\sin(px-pt)=\sin(px)\cos(pt)-\cos(px)\sin(pt).$$ Then you can rewrite the function as  $$ y(x)=\sin(px)\int_0^xf(t)\cos(pt)dt - \cos(px)\int_0^xf(t)\sin(pt)dt.$$ Now use the product rule and fundamental theorem of calculus to find the derivative and se